# CSS - Strange padding-top in Ubuntu

Tags: html, css, ubuntu

I feel a bit bored with the way websites were rendered in Ubuntu. You can see the labels I shot from Bootstrap. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

EDIT: I also tested with both Chrome and Firefox (in incognito mode without extensions).

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Are these screenshots from the official bootstrap pages? Or are these from an implemented bootstrap on a website of your own? Because it looks like a reset stylesheet missing.

Comment: Yes. It's from the official site of Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/. I don't see this issue in Mac or Windows.

Comment: These are the correct links to the content in question"
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel
I'm looking at the site with Firefox v21 using Kubuntu 12.10, and everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Yep, those are the links. Mine is Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.